# DOM to LaTeX resources/toolkits?

Tags: conversion, html

I want to convert some webpages to nicely formatted Latex documents. The webpage is a discussion forum, with deeply nested comments. Before I begin to write my own naive implementation, are there any tools/scripts which help with such html->latex structure transformation. For example, suppose a thread hierarchy is a simple `ul` `li` nesting , I need a tool that helps me put it into `itemize` blocks. And if possible, even for more complex `div` and `span` nesting.

Here is an example to make it more explicit:

```
<ul>
 <li>I am a parent comment of the root post. This is my opinion.</li>
 <ul>
     <li> I disagree with the parent and these are my opinions.</li>
     <ul>
         <li> Your opinion is wrong because of such and such facts. </li>
         <ul>
             <li> I am a deeply nested comment </li>
         </ul>
         <li> I agree, I also disagree with parent comment. </li>
     </ul>
  <li> I am another parent comment to the root post </li>
<ul>
```

To convert this to

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item I am a parent comment of the root post. This is my opinion.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item I disagree with the parent and these are my opinions.
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Your opinion is wrong because of such and such facts.
            \begin{itemize}
                 \item I am a deeply nested comment.
            \end{itemize}
            \item  I agree, I also disagree with parent comment.             
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \item I am another parent comment to the root post 
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: One way is to parse the webpage to some internal representation, and convert that to LaTeX. Examples of that kind of tools include [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) (Haskell) and [Kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/) (Ruby).

Comment: @morbusg do you know of alternatives for python/C/C++ ? Kramdown looks good.

Comment: ConTeXt can directly parse and typeset XML (and, by extension, XHTML). See for example http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/tas/

Comment: @yayu: sorry, I don't remember seeing one.